# How do I target the selected thumbnail in a Magnific Popup video gallery to make its opacity different from the other thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I target the selected thumbnail in a Magnific Popup video gallery to make its opacity different from the other thumbnails (default opacity is 0.7)? Current code below...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        // set opacity of video thumbnails...
        $('.video').css({"opacity": 0.7});
        $('.video').hover(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": 1.0});
            },function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": 0.7});
        });

        // INITIALISE MAGNIFIC POPUP
        $('.video').magnificPopup({
            type: 'iframe',
            iframe: {
            markup: '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler">'+
                        '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                        '<iframe class="mfp-iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen width="500" height="281" autoplay></iframe>'+
                        '<div class="mfp-title">Some caption</div>'+
                      '</div>',
            patterns: {
                vimeo: {
                  index: 'vimeo.com/',
                  id: '/',
                  src: '//player.vimeo.com/video/%id%?autoplay=1'
                }
            },  
            srcAction: 'iframe_src', // Templating object key. First part defines CSS selector, second attribute. "iframe_src" means: find "iframe" and set attribute "src".
          },
          callbacks: {
            markupParse: function(template, values, item) {
             values.title = item.el.attr('title');
            }
          }
        }); 

        // on thumbnail click
        $('.video').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); // tell browser to ignore its default behaviour on an anchor link
            // update thumbnails
            $('.video').css({"opacity": 0.7}); // reset selected element
            $(this).css({"opacity": 1.0}); // mark new selected element
        });         

    });
```

Comment: are you having trouble with the thumbnail click portion?

Comment: I would like to somehow integrate the effect of the thumbnail click portion into the callbacks{} function, but I'm unsure how to achieve it. So when a video thumbnail is clicked, it's opacity changes to 100% (from 70%), and it remains 'selected' when the magnific popup window closes so the user can see exactly which video they have just viewed.